# Python Boto3 shows incomplete information for the last record

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am writing a Python script using boto3 to export the information of some instances and print that information to the screen.
assuming that I have 10 instances running in an AWS region the script shows me the complete information of 9 instances, and the last one is shown incomplete

I have tried to modify the for sentence of my function but I have not been successful, what is wrong?

If i execute `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id XXX --region us-east-2` i can see all information

This is part of my code:

```
import boto3

def get_ec2_instances(ec2):
    for instances in ec2['Reservations']:
        for instance in instances['Instances']:
            print(instance['InstanceId'])
            print(instance['ImageId'])
            print(instance['InstanceType'])
            print(instance['KeyName'])
            print(instance['LaunchTime'])
            print(instance['Monitoring'])


client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2 = client.describe_instances()
get_ec2_instances(ec2)
```

Output:

> i-0000000000000000f - ami-000000006 - t3a.2xlarge - AWS - 2021-06-04 13:01:28+00:00 - {'State': 'disabled'}
>
> i-00000000000000009 - ami-000000006 - t3a.2xlarge - TestAWS - 2021-06-04 13:02:35+00 - {'State': 'disabled'}
>
> i-00000000000000001 - ami-000000036 - r4.xlarge
>
> PS C:\env>

**Update:**

I found that the printing crashes if a value is empty, I mean usually `instance['KeyName']` is null, if I try `print(instance['KeyName'])` the script crashes....

How can I resolve it?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is an issue with your console / shell, try adding a dummy `print("something")` after the `get_ec2_instancesx` call.

Comment: Note that `describe_instances` results are paginated. If `NextToken` is present in the response then you need to make an additional call with that token to get more results.

Comment: I think this is not a shell issue, the Test ran with success the message was printed, but the result still incompleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code might work, as it solves two problems in your approach:

1. It uses pagination to ensure that all instances get returned, even with there are multiple result pages (indicated by a `NextToken` key in the response).
2. It uses [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to access items from the result dictionary, avoiding `KeyError` exceptions when an expected key isn't present in the response and printing `None` instead in this case.

```py
import boto3


def get_ec2_instances(paginator):
    for page in paginator.paginate():
        for reservation in page['Reservations']:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']:
                print(instance.get('InstanceId'))
                print(instance.get('ImageId'))
                print(instance.get('InstanceType'))
                print(instance.get('KeyName'))
                print(instance.get('LaunchTime'))
                print(instance.get('Monitoring'))


client = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2_paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_instances')
get_ec2_instancesx(ec2_paginator)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get()` method instead.  It takes an optional default value and does not raise an exception.

```
print(instance.get('KeyName', 'KeyName is not in instance'))
```

Comment: It helps the community if you flag successful solutions.